# best adhesive for foam

Tags: adhesives

Best adhesive for glueing these back to back to make a double ply.

[image]

Comment: Best is a subjective word that can attract opinions so it is usually discouraged. What are you planning on doing with these. Do you have more of a description of what "it" is. I ask because foam is very broad and some glues are not to be used with some foams. So any indication of the composite would be useful here.

Comment: I want to make a thick cushion.  I have no way to tell what the material I have is made of but it seems like a kind of foam rubber.  Can you make a list of the most popular readily available glues and what materials they work with?

Comment: What exactly are "these"? The picture doesn't show the label in a readable way.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like normal EVA foam, which is often used in the cosplay community for making lightweight armour and the like (and of course for kneeling pads, children's play areas and the like).

I've successfully made prop helmets from EVA foam using **contact adhesive** to join the edges - they held up well despite the tension through the join. Given that you'll have a much greater surface area and much less tension on the join you'll have no trouble with it.

An alternative glue, widely used in the cosplay community, is **barge cement**, however I haven't used it so cannot personally confirm it's usefulness.

Comment: Good suggestions. I tried some auto headliner adhesive and it was ok, but if you are willing to deal with a bit of mess and paintbrushes contact cement works well on this foam and is quite strong.